# Is "excruciatingly painful" a correct phrase to use in a sentence since "excruciating" already means very painful?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, expressions

I have often come across the phrase "excruciatingly painful" in articles and even in short stories or novels, but is this a correct phrase? Since "excruciating" already means extremely painful, isn't this an avoidable repetition? I believe that saying "excruciatingly painful" would amount to saying something like "extremely painfully painful" and that wouldn't make sense.

Is my line of thinking correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: You're right that this is redundant. However, many phrases that are redundant like it have entered common English usage. Usually the redundancy gives extra emphasis to the meaning.

Comment: This is not redundant. Pain is scaled from 1 to 10. The word pain itself does not express the degree of pain being experienced. Excruciating can refer to both physical or mental pain. What is being described here is physical pain in the 9 - 10 range.

Answer (score 2):

(1) A second meaning of *excruciating* is extreme (in a bad way).

So, *excruciatingly bored*, *excruciating silence*, *excruciating embarrassment* mean extremely bored, extremely bad silence, extremely bad embarrassment.

So, *excruciatingly painful* could simply mean extremely painful.

(2) The use of two words with the same/redundant meaning next to each other is called a [*pleonasm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm). This is perfectly acceptable, especially in certain established idiomatic phrases:

- *mass exodus* = mass [mass departure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exodus);
- *safe haven* = safe [place of safety](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haven).

Also, *burning fire*, *tuna fish*, *frozen ice*, *foreign imports*, *past history*, *I myself* (*you yourself* etc.), *free gift*, *ATM machine*, and of course also *excruciatingly painful*.

(Also, legal terms such as *null and void*, *terms and conditions*, *cease and desist*---though some argue that in each case, the two words really do mean different things and so these aren't really pleonasms.)

We use pleonasms for emphasis, clarity, literary/poetic effect, or simply because it's a standard phrase.

Comment: I just wanna mention that legal stuff like "null and void", "terms and conditions", are usually there not because we find them fun but because someone somewhere had exercised their wit and managed to argue the two words somehow meant different things and thus CYA was exercised

Comment: @Raestloz: Good point! I've separated those examples out in a separate paragraph

Comment: @Raestloz - good catch. Legal documents often group terms in threes, at least UK ones, acts of parliament, writs, etc - e.g. _cease, desist and be at an end, take, remove and detain_.

Comment: Does anyone actually say _Loch Ness Lake_? I've never heard it here in the UK (though I agree with your other examples).

Comment: @KateBunting - Maybe Americans do, like they say 'London Town'. Left out was 'PIN number'.

Comment: @KateBunting: You're probably right. I've deleted that example

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So do the British say this: The Grand Canyon gorge? Most AmE speakers are familiar with Loch Ness monster, so the likelihood of appending lake is quite remote. Just as I assume that most British people have heard of the Grand Canyon.

Comment: @Lambie. No. Just the Grand Canyon.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, of course. My question was rhetorical.

Comment: @Lambie Place name tautologies do exist though.  Take "Glen Canyon" for example. Glen is literally a valley/gorge, from Gaelic.   There are also probably a few Glendales around the world. Dale is another word for a valley.

Comment: @BillyKerr  *You either take my point or you do not*. Again: In the same way, Americans would most likely *not say* Loch Ness lake, Brits would most likely **not say** Grand Canyon gorge.